# What's the difference between tf.feature_column.input_layer and tf.layers.Input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I currently get stuck at distinguishing between `tf.feature_column.input_layer` and `tf.layers.Input`. Are the two exchangable in the actual constructed model? What is the use case of each of the two?

Answer (score 2):

- [`tf.feature_column.input_layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/input_layer) returns a dense Tensor as an input layer to the Model from an already defined [FeatureColumn](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns). The FeatureColumn APIs [`tf.feature_column`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column) describes the attributes from the dataset that will be fed into an Estimator for training and validation.
- Whereas, [`tf.layers.Input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) is analogous to Keras `tf.keras.Input()` method which is used to instantiate a Keras or in this case TensorFlow Tensor for use with the [`tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) function.